# Error trying to place link in JQuery String

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to place a link in what I think is called a jquery string. But the problem is when I do the link doesn't appear. Could somebody explain to me how I would go about doing so?

This is where I am trying to place the link:

```
  var textarray = [
     "<a title=\"The TREWS\" href=\"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_17f7Abylvw\">
     The TREWS</a>";
  ];
```

I've tried:

```
 $("a").attr("href", "http://www.google.com/")
```

To no success

I've tried:
    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_17f7Abylvw\">The TREWS";
But this doesn't work either

Does anyone have the solution? I tried searching further in google but some of the words/vocabulary I didn't understand

Thanks

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e4zgzpjq/

Comment: The problem is when I try to place a link in the code, it doesn't appear. So I figure i'm writing the code improparly

Comment: Next time you create a fiddle please make sure to use the appropriate sections, like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/e4zgzpjq/2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is syntax error in code, remove `;` from array.

```
var textarray = ["<a title=\"The TREWS\"
                   href=\"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_17f7Abylvw\">The TREWS
                  </a>"; // <-- remove this extra ;
  ];
```

Working example below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Example</title>
  
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
  

<style>

body {-webkit-animation: pulse 200s infinite;animation: pulse 15s infinite;}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
    0% {background:#ffffff}
    3% {background:#ffffff}
    30% {background:#ffffff}
    60% {background:#ffffff}
    90% {background:#ffffff}
    100% {background:#ffffff}
}

@keyframes pulse {
    0% {background:#ffffff}
    3% {background:#ffffff}
    30% {background:#ffffff}
    60% {background:#ffffff}
    90% {background:#ffffff}
    100% {background:#ffffff}
}

.color-lightgrey
{
color: #E3E3E3;
letter-spacing: 0.6px;
margin-left: 1.5vw;
font-size: 2vw;
float: right;
font-style: italic;
}

.copypaste
{
font-size:1vw;
/*text-align:center;*/
/*vertical-align:middle;*/
text-align:-moz-center;
text-align:-webkit-center;
font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
padding-bottom: 6px;
}

.container
{    
/*position: absolute;*/
vertical-align:middle;
margin: auto;
display: table;
height: 100vh;
}
 
 
#random_text
{
font-size:3vw;
letter-spacing: 0.6px;
/*text-align:center;*/
/*vertical-align:middle;*/
text-align:-moz-center;
text-align:-webkit-center;
font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
padding-left: 5vw;
padding-right: 5vw;
}

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="random_text"></div>
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {

  $(window).resize(function() {
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var containerHeight = $(".container").height();
    $(".container").css("top", (windowHeight / 2 - containerHeight * 0.7) + "px");
  });

  var textarray = ["<a title=\"The TREWS\" href=\"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_17f7Abylvw\">The TREWS</a>"
  ];
  
  var firstTime = true;

  function RndText() {
    var rannum = Math.floor(Math.random() * textarray.length);
    if (firstTime) {
      $('#random_text').fadeIn('fast', function() {
        $(this).html(textarray[rannum]).fadeOut('fast');
      });
      firstTime = false;
    }
    $('#random_text').fadeOut('fast', function() {
      $(this).html(textarray[rannum]).fadeIn('fast');
    });
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var containerHeight = $(".container").height();
    // $(".container").css("top", (windowHeight / 2 - containerHeight * 0.7) + "px");
  }

  $(function() {
    // Call the random function when the DOM is ready:
    RndText();
  });
  var inter = setInterval(function() {
    RndText();
  }, 3000);
});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to parse the string into html before doing anything

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/

Once you have the html ready, you can then change the attribute. And get rid of the ; as well.

Answer (score 0):

I was about to point out the syntax error too. That jsfiddle won't work, for starters jquery should be defined in the external resources. Here is a really simple version of your jsfiddle that adds the link without using the array. Hope it helps point you in the right direction.

[jsfiddle.net/duu8a7tx/](http://jsfiddle.net/duu8a7tx/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // one way to do it
  $('#random_text').html('<a title="The TREWS" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_17f7Abylvw">The TREWS</a>');

  // another way
  var link = $('<a>The TREWS</a>');
  link.attr('href', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_17f7Abylvw');
  link.attr('title', 'The TREWS');
  $('#random_text2').html(link);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="random_text">this text wont show</div>
<div id="random_text2">this text wont show</div>
```